# "Missing Package Version" when installing Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, npm

I am looking to set up Google Firebase Functions from the Command line. I can successfully deploy, but when I try to install the functions. Here is the complete readout:

````
npm ERR! Can't install /Users/[username]/Documents/firebaseNode/functions: Missing package version

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/[username]/.npm/_logs/2019-09-21T16_11_22_371Z-debug.log```



I have tried to locate the missing packages but cannot get any information. 

```17 verbose stack Error: Can't install /Users/[username]/Documents/nodeFolder/functions: Missing package version
17 verbose stack     at hasMinimumFields (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/validate-args.js:28:15)
17 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
17 verbose stack     at LOOP (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:15:14)
17 verbose stack     at chain (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:20:5)
17 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/validate-args.js:16:5
17 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:52:35
17 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
17 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:52:11
17 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
17 verbose stack     at asyncMap (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:51:8)
17 verbose stack     at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/validate-args.js:15:3)
17 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
17 verbose stack     at LOOP (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:15:14)
17 verbose stack     at chain (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:20:5)
17 verbose stack     at Installer.loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:477:3)
17 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
18 verbose cwd /Users/[username]/Documents/nodeFolder/functions
19 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
20 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g"
21 verbose node v8.11.4
22 verbose npm  v6.11.3```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code solved my issue with this:

```
npm install -g npm
npm update
npm install
```